Eplan P8 multiline schematics and free form
I am very new to Eplan P8 and come from schematic making in PCB designing softwares, where you can basically connect anything to anything.
I am finding it very challenging that even basic stuff like multiple nodes connection, connecting on pin to multiple outputs and splitting a cable into many to connect multiple devices is so difficult.
I also found I cannot make cable loops. E.g. in a connecto I want to interconnect pin1 and pin2 and it throws a lot of errors.
Can someone also guide me if I can turn-off this automatic connections if possible.

How to use some piece of software might not be exactly an electrical engineering question. Does the sofware have a tutorial or manual how to use it?

Remember that when you're wiring terminals on devices instead of solder pads on a PCB there might be regulatory limitations on how many wires you're allowed to connect to each screw. On terminal blocks there are typically bridge bars or jumpers to connect together multiple terminals that have their own connection facilities beside the screws/springs/etc for the regular wiring.
